# "Country" or the "countryside"

Tags: word-choice

Isn't it wrong to say "to go to the countryside" instead of "to go to the country?"

A word for word translation from Russian would be "to go to the village".That probably doesn't work in English.

Comment: Please explain why you think it is wrong to say, ""to go to the countryside".  What are you basing this on?

Comment: Obviously you can say 'go to the village' if the destination is a particular village, but if it just means 'to a rural area', you probably want 'country'.

Comment: Yes, exactly it is a rural area. A village in that area, Kate Bunting. That probably wasn't written by a native speaker, chasly-supporys Monica. I read about it on a forum.

Comment: I think we need more context. Are you going to a village or to the countryside? Please give an entire sentence, not just the isolated phrase. Thanks.

Comment: I mean people go to to villages which are out of town in the country. Sorry, if confused you. I thought "a village" and "the country" or the "countrysude" mean the same thing.

Comment: I thought all three mean the same.

Comment: A village is a small settlement _in_ the country.

Answer (score 1):

A village isn't the countryside. The countryside is fields, forests, farms.  A village is made of houses, shops, a church and a pub.

A village is usually surrounded by countryside, but they are not the same.

The word "country" is best used as a modifier.

So you might say:

> At the weekend I like to take a walk in the countryside. We will often stop at a country pub and enjoy a pint.

> Last summer I visited the pretty village of Little Snoring.

> In Russia many people own a dacha in the countryside which they visit during the weekend and summer holidays  (Note: for the specifically Russian cultural word, we use the borrowed word).

Comment: So "to go to the countryside" means going to the rural area. The countryside is the whole area. "To go to the country or village" which are in the countryside means to go to your dacha. I hope I don't misunderstand.

Comment: Of course dacha are a russian thing.  I think some dacha are in villages, and some are not.  The countryside isn't one place so it rather odd to say go to the countryside.  And I would avoid "country" except in combination with other words  (country pub)  I think the best phrase to use is "in the countryside" as in "We spend weekends in the countryside" rather than "go to...."